# How do you use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() to alter the USER EDIT form?

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I'm trying to mark fields on the `/user/_uid_/edit` screen as disabled.
These are custom fields I've created in `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields` in D8.

I have this code for another node entity type...

```php
function MODULENAME_form_node_survey_edit_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_content_type']['widget']['#type'] = 'hidden';
}
```

This works as expected, and on the node/123/edit screen for a that content type, that field is hidden. (works as expected)

(it gets populated by a migration process, and needs to stay how its set, even if users change other fields...)

My problem is, that I'm trying to disable a field on the USER-EDIT screen, such as /user/123/edit.

I'm trying the EXACT same code structure.

```php
function MODULENAME_form_user_edit_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['field_organization_reference']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I've tried throwing in class changes, and other things to alter the input fields, but they don't work.

```php
$form['field_organization_reference']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
$form['field_organization_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';    
$form['field_organization_reference']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'borkbork';    
$form['field_organization_name']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'borkbork';
$form['field_organization_name']['widget']['#type'] = 'hidden';
```

All as attempts to try and change something on the user edit form.

But nothing is working.

Is `user-edit` the correct form id?   Is there something else I'm missing

Thoughts? Help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Your code...
}
```

Inspecting element, I see the form id is `user-form`, which needs to be translated to the machine-readable name `user_form`

Otherwise, you can always do a standard `HOOK_form_alter()`:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_form') {
    // Your code...
  }
}
```

And always clear cache after adding/changing hook names.

Comment: `MYMODULE_form_user_form_alter` was the big help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I was helped with.

```php
function MODULENAME_form_user_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

      if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('administer users')) {

        $form['field_organization_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';  
        $form['field_organization_reference']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';    

      }

}
```

The important part being **user* in the function name.  not `user-edit` or `user_edit`.

The next challange was figuring out that the ORG REF field (being a auto complete reference) has a different structure then the name, which is plain text.

I used `dpm($form['field_name'])` on both, inside the function, and as UID 1 you can see the output of that dpm() call.

The IF check makes sure that admins can still see the fields to edit the user directly if they need to.